# Converting a vector with numerical and NA values to a vector with binary values

Tags: r, missing-data

I want to convert a vector with negative values `(-inf,0]` and `NA` to `0` and all positive values `(0,inf)` to the same new vector with binary variables in R for use in logistic regression.

More specifically, my data set `med` consists of a matrix with a vector which can be retrieved with `med$Amount_total`. This vector consists of numbers ranging from -10,000 to 100,000 as well as NA values. I want to convert these to a vector with 0s in the place of negative, 0 and NA values and convert all positive values to 1s for use in a glm (logistic regression model) that I'm going to fit to the other vectors in med.

example:

```
input <- c(50,NA,-4,32,0,0,12)
desired_output <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
```

Comment: How about `ifelse(is.na(x) | x<=0,0,1)` with `x` being your vector.

Comment: Hi @Ali if any of the answers solves your pb you might click on "accept it" so that other people know that it was solved. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
a=c(50,NA,-4,32,0,0,12)
(a>0 &!is.na(a)) + 0
```

`a` is your input vector, inside the parenthesis there is the combination of your desired condition. It creates a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE. To transform it into a boolean vector you can force it into numeric with `as.numeric` or add zero, which has the same effect.

```
#### [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
as.integer(replace(v1, is.na(v1)|v1 < 0, 0)!=0)
```

Or

```
as.integer(!(is.na(v1) | v1 <= 0))
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```